# Disable button permanently by code in android

Tags: android

I want to disable  button permanently after click on it. I am trying several time, but when I close the app or go back to the previous layout it remain enable.

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {

            Integer t = count * 650;
            String tot = t.toString();
            selectseat.setText(selectseat.getText().toString() + " A1 ");
            fair.setText("Fair: " + tot);
            btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            btn1.setEnabled(false);

              /* if(flag == 1)
                 {
                   btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    btn1.setEnabled(false);
                   Log.d("ins", "called");
                 }
               flag = 0;*/

            count++;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no means for you to "permanently" disable a widget. You can disable a particular *instance* of a widget, using `setEnabled(false)`, as you have in your question. You will simply need to track yourself that this widget is "permanently" disabled (e.g., save that data in `SharedPreferences`), then use `setEnabled()` to disable it on future runs of your app.

Comment: can you please help me how to save data in SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your activity state in order to disable the button when you return back to that activity.

Try: [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-on-android?rq=1)